# MPMoviePlayerController Stack Overflow

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to use `MPMoviePlayerController` in a fairly simple iPhone app.  The basic layout is an `UIApplicationDelegate` associated with a `UIWindow` xib file.  Within the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method, I'm trying to play a movie with the following code:

```
// Path to the movie
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logoscreen" ofType:@"m4v"];      
movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

// Setup the player
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

// Use the new 3.2 style API  
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;  
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;  
[window addSubview:moviePlayer.view];  

[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

When this executes, I get an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error, and the GDB loads a huge stack (with the "_makeSubtreePerformSelector" method repeating several thousand times:

```
#6633   0x34b0cb0c in -[UIView(Hierarchy)         _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
#6634   0x34b0cb0c in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
#6635   0x34b0cb0c in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
#6636   0x34b0cb0c in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]
#6637   0x34b0c9c4 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:]
#6638   0x34b0c790 in -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
#6639   0x34b0c408 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:]
#6640   0x33f81928 in -[MPInlineVideoViewController _transitionToFullscreenAnimated:]
#6641   0x33f7df5c in -[MPInlineVideoViewController setFullscreen:animated:]
#6642   0x33f05998 in -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew setFullscreen:animated:]
#6643   0x33f059cc in -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew setFullscreen:]
#6644   0x33f06b2c in -[MPMoviePlayerController setFullscreen:]
#6645   0x00002ab0 in -[GiyapLiteAppDelegate playMovie:] at GiyapLiteAppDelegate.m:67
#6646   0x000028a2 in -[GiyapLiteAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] at GiyapLiteAppDelegate.m:38
#6647   0x34b16154 in -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:]
#6648   0x34cc46d4 in -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:]
#6649   0x34b7f7c0 in -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
#6650   0x34b7eebc in -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
#6651   0x34b7e7f0 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent
#6652   0x33910ee4 in PurpleEventCallback
#6653   0x322352b2 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
#6654   0x322371dc in __CFRunLoopDoSource1
#6655   0x32238194 in __CFRunLoopRun
#6656   0x321df0c2 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#6657   0x321defd0 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#6658   0x34b0ab20 in -[UIApplication _run]
#6659   0x34b08fc0 in UIApplicationMain
#6660   0x000026f8 in main at main.m:14
```

It's worth noting that if I try the code that plays the movie based on a click event, it works just fine.  It's almost like the application hasn't finished "wiring" something up yet in regards to the window hierarchy?  Has anyone encountered anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try setting `animated` to No.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that didn't seem to work, same error.  I then tried setting all "YES" values above to "NO", and the best result I could achieve is the movie just doesn't play.